# Mongodb find match query on array field doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following schema with colletcion &  there values associated with it my mongodb. And following is example document of this one.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590d46d685a155f33a4a1f1d"),
    "domainName" : "gmail.com",
    "userlevels" : [ 
        {
            "labId" : 104,
            "userlevel" : true
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : 401,
            "userlevel" : false
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : 202,
            "userlevel" : true
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : 102,
            "userlevel" : true
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : 108,
            "userlevel" : true
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : 110,
            "userlevel" : true
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : 120,
            "userlevel" : true
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : 820,
            "userlevel" : false
        }
    ],
    "labconfigs" : [ 
        ObjectId("590d46d685a155f33a4a1f0c"), 
        ObjectId("590d46d685a155f33a4a1f11"), 
        ObjectId("590d46d685a155f33a4a1f10"), 
        ObjectId("590d46d685a155f33a4a1f0d"), 
        ObjectId("590d46d685a155f33a4a1f12"), 
        ObjectId("590d46d685a155f33a4a1f0f"), 
        ObjectId("590d46d685a155f33a4a1f0e"), 
        ObjectId("591087b0b18c5f472905343a")
    ]
}
```

So what we want is all documents matching within particular range of labID, with only fields which are matching in array ("userlevels") to be in result output.

Say if we want all matching documents in collection with range between $gt 100 to lt 200 , **then following desired output should come.**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590d46d685a155f33a4a1f1d"),
    "domainName" : "gmail.com",
    "userlevels" : [ 
        {
            "labId" : 104,
            "userlevel" : true
        },
        {
            "labId" : 102,
            "userlevel" : true
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : 108,
            "userlevel" : true
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : 110,
            "userlevel" : true
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : 120,
            "userlevel" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

What i have tried & this is my mongodb query.

```
            db.collection('domains').find({
                                           "userlevels":{ $all :[
                                               { "$elemMatch" : { "labId" :{$gte : 100, $lt:200 }}}
                                               ]}
                                          }).toArray(function(err, items) {
              console.log("items",items);
                                 });
```

It replies with all documents matching documents within range of lab_id's (100 to 200) , but it replies in userlevels with lab_id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mongodb version 3.0 & below use this query which worked for me.

```
    db.collection('domains').aggregate({
            $match: {
                "userlevels.labId": {
                    $gt: 100,
                    $lt: 200
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project: {
                domainName: 1,
                userlevels: {
                    "$setDifference": [{
                        $map: {
                        input: "$userlevels",
                        as: "result",
                        in: {
                            $cond: [{
                                $and: [{
                                    $gt: ["$$result.labId", 100]
                                }, {
                                    $lt: ["$$result.labId", 200]
                                }, {
                                    $eq: ["$$result.userlevel", true]
                                }]
                            },
                                "$$result",
                                false
                            ]
                        }
                    }},
                   [false]
                  ]
                }
            }
        }

     })
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use aggregation pipeline.

Initial `$match` to limit the documents that have at least one `userlevels` array element with matching `labId` criteria followed by `$filter` with `cond` to limit the elements in the array to the matching `labId` criteria in each of the matching document.

`$project` to include(1) `domainName` and overwrite the `userlevels` with filtered value.

```
aggregate({
    $match: {
        "userlevels.labId": {
            $gt: 100,
            $lt: 200
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        domainName: 1,
        userlevels: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$userlevels",
                as: "result",
                cond: {
                    $and: [{
                        $gt: ["$$result.labId", 100]
                    }, {
                        $lt: ["$$result.labId", 200]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: 1. What does domainName: 1 means ? . 2. Also in projection $filter, can we add new cond to match elements with 'userauth':true along with $gt & $lt

Comment: Np.  Updated answer to add more explanation. Yes, you can `$and` `userlevel:true` in the `cond`

Comment: Something like `{
                    $and: [{
                        $gt: ["$$result.labId", 100]
                    }, {
                        $lt: ["$$result.labId", 200]
                    }, {$eq:["$$result.userlevel", true]}]`

Comment: Would this query work on Mongo 3.0 ? i know it is not working on 2.6.12 & it is working on 3.4.

Comment: No, it will work from 3.2 & above. For 3.0 & below versions, you have to replace filter part with set operator. More here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605431/how-to-filter-array-of-sub-documents

Comment: I am trying to figure out from long time, clue you have give me, but not able to get it. Can you please elaborate? I couldn't see any set operator in example. it was just map

Comment: `setDifference` is the set operator. The logic is to use `$cond`itional expression in a `$map` to project a `userlevel` row if query is matched else `false` followed by `setDifference` to remove the `false` values and what left is your matching rows, which is what `$filter` does.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
db.domains.aggregate([
    { $unwind : '$userlevels'},
    { $match : { 'userlevels.labId' : { $gt: 100, $lt: 200 } }},
    { $group : {
        '_id' : '$_id',
        'domainName': { '$first' : '$domainName'},
        "userlevels": { "$push": "$userlevels" }
    }}
]);
```

Comment: How can we do it in Mongo 3.0 ?